# java : For loop isn't breaking after reaching a particular condition .

Tags: java

I am in the process of reading only latest 10 Files (by creation date ) from a folder using apache.commons jar

This is listing all the files , but i don't know why this isn't stopping even after completion of reading 10 files

This is my code , but i don't know why it is not stopping

```
import org.apache.commons.io.comparator.LastModifiedFileComparator;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dir = new File("D:\\MyFolder");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        Arrays.sort(files, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

             if(files.length==10)
             {
             // return;
                 break ; 
             }

            File file = files[i];
            System.out.printf(file.getName()+"\n");


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong condition

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        File file = files[i];
        System.out.printf(file.getName()+"\n");
    }
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.length && i < 10; i++) {

        File file = files[i];
        System.out.printf(file.getName()+"\n");
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `&&` otherwise this will throw an Exception if file.length < 10

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if(files.length==10)
```

to

```
if(i == 10)
```

You're always comparing to the length of the File array.

Comment: Then the `i == 10` condition will never be met, and the loop will iterate `files.length` times.

Comment: @PauKiatWee then the condition doesn't matter anyway, because you won't need to break out of the loop prematurely, since you can just let it complete normally

Comment: Nothing, everything works as expected. It should just break if it reaches the 11th file.

Answer (score 1):

The condition should be `if (i == 10)`, because `files.length` does not change with each iteration of the loop. Better yet, change your code as follows:

```
int end = Math.min(files.length, 10);
for (int i = 0; i < end ; i++) {
    // ... your code
}
```

This would calculate the ending index once, and avoid recalculations in the loop.